# The polarization lattice of a non-polar one dimensional chain

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I have been trying to understand the concept of dielectric polarization in material science mostly by following [Nicola Spaldin's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1831)

I am confused by the claim that the polarization of a non-polar chain (with alternating equal and equally spaced positive and negative point charges) is a lattice $\pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm\frac{3}{2},...$. This is consistent with the modern theory of polarization, but I could not verify this explicitly by computation.

I was able to choose two unit cells such that the simple computation gives polarizations $\pm \frac{1}{2}$, but what are the calculations that give the other values in the polarization lattice (i.e. $\pm \frac{3}{2},..$)?

I tried choosing different supercells containing arbitrary numbers of positive and negative pairs, but the answers always come out as $\pm \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago but just came back to check how this is going! Have you found out an answer? Are you still working on this?